# Android new Intent with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I'm developing Android application that uses fragment. The menu list will be appear when you click the top left menu icon. After clicking a menu item, it creates a new Intent and start a new Activity that also uses fragment with the same menu order. The problem is when the new activity started, it will immediately call the Intent of the first menu item. I don't want to change the order for each activity but I want the app only switch to other activity when user click on a menu item. How to make program like that?

For example, if this is the onSectionAttached method of Activity1. It will immediately switch to MainActivity when Activity1 started. How to make the app only switch to MainActivity if user click on the menu?

Bakteri.java

```
package com.example.app02;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Bakteri extends Activity implements
    NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    static DBHelper dbhelper;
    static Cursor c=null;
    static ListView list;
    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the
     * navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in
     * {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,
                        PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();
        Intent intent;
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                //To start a new activity
                intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }



    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        protected Context context;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);

            //access database
            dbhelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
            try {
                dbhelper.createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new Error("Unable to create database");
            }
            try {
                dbhelper.openDataBase();
            }catch(SQLException sqle){
                throw sqle;
            }


            final TextView txvMain = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.result);
            txvMain.setText("Bakteri");
            list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            final EditText search = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search);
            search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
                    ArrayList<String> list_title = new ArrayList();
                    ArrayList<String> list_content = new ArrayList();
                    if(!s.equals("")){
                        c=dbhelper.query("bakteri", null, "nama_ilmiah LIKE '%" + search.getText() + "%'", null, null,null, null);
                        String res = "";
                        if(c.moveToFirst())
                        {
                            do {
                                list_title.add(c.getString(0));
                                list_content.add(c.getString(1));

                                res += c.getString(0) + "\n" + c.getString(1) + "\n"  + "\n";
                            } while (c.moveToNext());
                        }
                        String[] title = new String[ list_title.size() ];
                        list_title.toArray(title);
                        String[] content = new String[ list_content.size() ];
                        list_content.toArray(content);
                        CustomList adapter = new CustomList(getActivity(), title, content);
                                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                        //txvMain.setText(res);
                    }
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){

                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){

                }


            });

                        //set a drawable as the background of the textView

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (dbhelper != null) {
            dbhelper.close();
        }
    }
}
```

NavigationDrawerFragment.java

```
package com.example.app02;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation
 * drawer. See the <a href=
 * "https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction"
 * > design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors
 * implemented here.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the
     * user manually expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated
        // awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState
                    .getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of
        // actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView
                .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        selectItem(position);
                    }
                });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar()
                .getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
                        getString(R.string.title_home),
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                        getString(R.string.title_section4),
                        getString(R.string.title_section5)}));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null
                && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation
     * drawer interactions.
     * 
     * @param fragmentId
     *            The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout
     *            The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), /* host Activity */
        mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open, /*
                                         * "open drawer" description for
                                         * accessibility
                                         */
        R.string.navigation_drawer_close /*
                                         * "close drawer" description for
                                         * accessibility
                                         */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to
                    // prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true)
                            .apply();
                }

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce
        // them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(
                    "Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar.
        // See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the
        // action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to
     * show the global app 'context', rather than just what's in the current
     * screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return getActivity().getActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must
     * implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: use onNavigationDrawerItemSelected method

Comment: I use switch(position) inside onNavigationDrawerItemSelected to start a new Activity. But 'case 0' is executed before user click the menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Remove onSectionAttached logic.
And keep it only onNavigationDrawerItemSelected or whatever your callback is called.

Comment: '@Override
 public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
  // update the main content by replacing fragments
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
  fragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container,
      PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();
  Intent i;
  switch(position){
  case 1:
   startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
   break;
  }
 }'   It doesn't work

Comment: I've provided the full code. The problem is when this Activity is started, it will switch to the MainActivity even if I didn't click the menu item.

Comment: Can you provide you NavigationDrawer fragment and add "default" to your switch with empty break;

Comment: `case 0:
             intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
             break;
         default:
          break;`